# Why can't I compare this numbers in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, comparison

So, I have an `if statement` that checks if the `$chosenCourseId` is equals to `$thisCertificateCourseId` OR if it's equals to `0`.

I get it wright when it compares to `0`, but if the `$chosenCourseId` is equals any other number, it doesn't match the `$thisCertificateCourseId`, even if they are the same `2740 == 2740`.

The comparison occours on PHP code that echoes to the Ajax and display the number of certificates of that course (between two dates).

The thing is that if I run only the PHP code it echoes the number itself `$thisCertificateCourseId = 2740` but when I `console.log()` it, it returns `NULL`.

Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

PHP Code:

```
$certificateCounter = 0;
foreach ($certificates as $certificate) {

    $thisCertificateCourseId = unserialize($certificate['certificate_course_id'])[0];
    $thisCertificateTimestamp = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($certificate['time_stamp']));

if($thisCertificateTimestamp >= $minDate 
    AND $thisCertificateTimestamp <= $maxDate
    AND ($chosenCourseId == $thisCertificateCourseId OR $chosenCourseId == 0)
) {

    $certificateCounter++;

  }

}
```

PHP Code to `console.log()`:

```
$certificateCounter = 0;
$icounter = 0;
foreach ($certificates as $certificate) {

    $thisCertificateCourseId = unserialize($certificate['certificate_course_id'])[0];
    $thisCertificateTimestamp = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($certificate['time_stamp']));

    $certificateCourseId[$icounter] = $thisCertificateCourseId;
    $icounter++;

}
```

jQuery to `console.log()`:

```
jQuery.each(data[10], function(index, value) {
    console.log(index + ' -> ' + value);
});
```

PHP Code running by itself:

```
$chosenCourseId = 2740;

$certificateCounter = 0;
foreach ($certificates as $certificate) {

    $thisCertificateCourseId = $certificate['certificate_course_id'];
    $thisCertificateTimestamp = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($certificate['time_stamp']));

    echo 'Raw: ';
    var_dump($thisCertificateCourseId);
    echo "<BR>";
    echo "Unserialized: ";
    var_dump(unserialize($thisCertificateCourseId));
    echo "<BR>";
    echo "[0]: ";
    var_dump(unserialize($thisCertificateCourseId)[0]);
    echo "<BR>";
    echo "Is equal? ";
    var_dump(unserialize($thisCertificateCourseId)[0] == $chosenCourseId);
    echo "<BR><BR>";

}
```

Results of PHP Code running by itself:

```
Raw: string(51) "a:3:{i:0;s:4:"1139";i:1;s:4:"2968";i:2;s:4:"2968";}" 
Unserialized: array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "1139" [1]=> string(4) "2968" [2]=> string(4) "2968" } 
[0]: string(4) "1139" 
Is equal? bool(false) 

Raw: string(21) "a:1:{i:0;s:4:"1139";}" 
Unserialized: array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "1139" } 
[0]: string(4) "1139" 
Is equal? bool(false) 

Raw: string(51) "a:3:{i:0;s:4:"2740";i:1;s:4:"2968";i:2;s:4:"2968";}" 
Unserialized: array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "2740" [1]=> string(4) "2968" [2]=> string(4) "2968" } 
[0]: string(4) "2740" 
Is equal? bool(true)
```

---

Edit:

So i figured out that both variables `$chosenCourseId` and `$thisCertificateCourseId` are strings with `is_string()` that returned me `true`. On the other hand `is_numeric()` returned me `false` on both variables.

When `$chosenCourseId` and `$thisCertificateCourseId` is `2740`:
`strcmp($chosenCourseId, $thisCertificateCourseId)` returns me `-47`.

This statement never triggers (I know that `2740` is one of the numbers/strings):

```
if($thisCertificateCourseId == 2740 OR $thisCertificateCourseId == '2740') {
    $certificateCounter++;
}
```

If I try the code below, it works, but I need to know if that certificate is from the course chosen by user.

```
if(true){
    $certificateCounter++;
}
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

---

filterDashboard() returns code:

```
return array(
    $courseList,                            // 0
    $unitList,                              // 1
    $certificatesList,              // 2
    $quizScoreList,                     // 3
    $authorList,                            // 4
    $authorsPosition,                   // 5
    $authorsPercent,                    // 6
    $unitSeconds,                           // 7
    $totalSecondsConverted,     // 8
    $certificateCounter,            // 9
    $certificateCourseId,           // 10
);
```

`echo json_encode(filterDashboard($units, $certificates, $quizzes, $minDate, $maxDate, $authorsId, $courseOf, $chosenCourseId, $chosenUnitId));`

```
jQuery.each(data, function(index, value) {
    console.log(index + ' -> ' + value);
});
```

returns:

```
0 -> [object Object],[object Object]
1 -> [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
2 -> 
3 -> 
4 -> [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
5 -> 1
6 -> 100,00
7 -> [object Object]
8 -> 34min 3s
9 -> 0
10 -> a:3:{i:0;s:4:\"1139\";i:1;s:4:\"2968\";i:2;s:4:\"2968\";},a:1:{i:0;s:4:\"1139\";},a:3:{i:0;s:4:\"2740\";i:1;s:4:\"2968\";i:2;s:4:\"2968\";},a:3:{i:0;s:4:\"2968\";i:1;s:4:\"2968\";i:2;s:4:\"2968\";},a:2:{i:0;s:4:\"2968\";i:1;s:4:\"2968\";}
```

Comment: Check the precedence for logical operators in PHP : http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php - `$chosenCourseId == $thisCertificateCourseId OR $chosenCourseId == 0` I'm not certain as I never use *AND / OR* operators but I don't think that's going to do what you think it will...

Comment: @CD001, thanks for your answer but I've used `$chosenCourseId == $thisCourseId OR $chosenCourseId == 0` (note that I've changed the `$thisCertificateCourseId` for `$thisCourseId` because there was another comparison) before and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Was just a comment ;) I've just checked, only really matters with assignment not comparison it seems... incidentally your max_date isn't further in the future than Jan 19th 2038 is it?

Comment: @CD001, the date is ok, the line it must return is June 02, 2016.

Comment: So i figured out that both variables `$chosenCourseId` and `$thisCertificateCourseId` are strings with `is_string()` that returned me `true`. On the other hand `is_numeric()` returned me `false` on both variables.

Comment: You may also have a slightly odd date comparison `$thisCertificateTimestamp = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($certificate['time_stamp']));` then `$thisCertificateTimestamp >= $minDate` ... which means you're doing a string comparison on the dates; assuming they're both in `Y-m-d` format it *should* work, just seems a little odd.

Comment: @CD001, yeah, they both have the same format. I've tested it already and when I select the range that contains May 02, 2016, it triggers it and display the certificate, when I select another range, it doens't display the range. The thing here is when I select a course id to check certificates of that course id. Please take a look at Edit.

Comment: It actually seems to be working on my machine... but I've extrapolated the source data

Comment: @CD001, This statement never triggers: `if($thisCertificateCourseId == 2740 OR $thisCertificateCourseId == '2740') { $certificateCounter++; }`. Any thoughts?

Comment: @CD001, it actually works when I run it separately from the ajax/json, i don't know what's happening...

Comment: You're not trying to get JavaScript to parse data encoded with PHP's `serialize()` function rather than `json_encode()` are you?

Comment: @CD001, the PHP is calling a function `echo json_encode(filterDashboard())` and the JS is getting this `echo` with the part it's in my question above `jQuery to console.log():`. I can get the `$certificateCounter` with the jQuery, if I put `if(true){ $certificateCounter++; }` it returns me `5` (the number of certificates in database).

Comment: Any chance you could grab a snippet from that echo? The PHP side is fine so it has to be something to do with either the structure of that output json or the way it's parsed.

Comment: @CD001, do you have a fast way of doing this? Should I get the `index` and `value` of each `data`?

Comment: @CD001, please take a look if that's what you need (I've edited the question).

Comment: Ah - JavaScript isn't going to understand `data[10]` that's PHP serialized data inside the JSON so JS will just treat it as that massive string, literally. `data[10][1]` for instance should equal `:` in JavaScript since even strings are Objects in JS.

Comment: @CD001, sorry, my mistake, I'm using `data[9]` to get the `$certificateCounter`. But the `data[10]`, shouldn't it get the `value` of each and `console.log()` it?

Comment: assuming `data` is that list then `data[10] = 'a:3:{i:0; ... "2968\";}';` (as a massive string) so your console log for that record should be `10 -> a:3:{i:0; ... "2968\";}`

Comment: @CD001, I've updates `PHP Code to console.log()` with the correct code, and it returns me the value of `null` when running the code below it `jQuery to console.log():`.

Comment: @CD001, if I `$certificateCourseId[$icounter] = intval($thisCertificateCourseId);`, then it `console.log()` `0`. but that's because it `null == 0` when converted.

Comment: @CD001, it seems that the serialized object is not a serialized in the PHP code... but outside of it it's... I'll try something.

Comment: ... well I'm slightly lost following this through ... and I'll be afk for at least an hour; you'll probably have worked it out by then! :)

Comment: @CD001, thank you so much for the help, I got it! I'll explain on my answer but it seems that ajax/json put some slashes on my serialized string when sending the array `$certificates` to PHP, so it never got unserialized there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.
The thing here was because I'm passing an array through the ajax/json and in the PHP end it was adding slashes to the serialized array.

I resolved it using `stripcslashes()` before unserializing the string.

Follow the working code:

```
$certificateCounter = 0;
foreach ($certificates as $certificate) {

    $thisCertificateCourseId = unserialize(stripcslashes($certificate['certificate_course_id']))[0];
    $thisCertificateTimestamp = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($certificate['time_stamp']));

    if($thisCertificateTimestamp >= $minDate
        AND $thisCertificateTimestamp <= $maxDate
        AND ($chosenCourseId == $thisCertificateCourseId OR $chosenCourseId == 0)
    ) {
        $certificateCounter++;
    }

}
```

Comment: You should accept your own answer if it'll be helpful to anyone else with the same problem ;)

Comment: @CD001, sure, I was just waiting for the 2 days that stackoverflow requests to accept my own answer. Cheers!